# Where did 'flag to close' just vanish to?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, flagging

I'm reasonably sure that I typically see an option to flag a question as deserving closure for the usual reasons (since I don't have enough reputation to vote to close). Yet, upon encountering [Managing conflict with coworkers to relieve a hostile work environment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/41484/acute-hostile-work-environment-what-should-i-do), I found no such option in the flag menu. I left a custom flag with my suggestion that this was a closure candidate, but, am I imagining things?

Comment: that's just a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) - question was closed while you were looking at it, which dropped the option from flag dialog

Comment: Oh! I guess next time I'll treat that as a clue.

Answer (score 6):

Like gnat said, it was closed so you couldn't flag it.

Regardless, thanks for flagging things! While flags often create work for us moderators it all helps contribute to a better site.